# installing a backup second thermostat

Tags: wiring

I currently have a Honeywell T5 wifi thermostat in my workshop that works almost the way I need it to. The only shortcoming is that when the weather is -30C for an extended period the temps in there will fall well below freezing if I have it shut off. The T5 has the ability to adjust temp and also set mode to OFF / ON while still being able to see the actual temp remotely.
The T5 only goes down to +10C and I want the second stat to cut in if the temp in there falls below +2C to +3C regardless if the mode on the T5 is OFF. Most days it will stay above +4C as long as the sun is shining and the out door temp is above -10C. 
I have a 120V / 20A baseboard stat that goes that low and would like to use it to over ride the T5 even if it is turned off. My concern is that if it is turned off or on and the second one over rides it will the voltage spike damage the T5?
Any ideas on protecting the T5?
I just wish the T5 would go down low enough.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What is the T5 controlling?  A typical HVAC system with low voltage control?

Comment: This is a 24V 'stat.  Did you hook it up with a "C" wire?

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica, right, OP mentioned baseboard heat, so I wanted to make sure the current thermostat wasn't wired _creatively_ to something else like that.

Comment: Did you have a backup before you installed the  T5?

Comment: Can you post photos of the wiring at the thermostat?

Answer (score 1):

> I have a 120V / 20A baseboard stat that goes that low and would like to use it to over ride the T5 even if it is turned off. My concern is that if it is turned off or on and the second one over rides it will the voltage spike damage the T5? Any ideas on protecting the T5?

You don't say whether the T5 is controlling the electric baseboard heat or some other heat system.

If it's controlling some other heat system, there's no issue at all letting the baseboard thermostat switch separate baseboard heat on and off.  This is a pretty common setup.

If the T5 is controlling a relay / contactor that's switching the baseboard heat, I can't see any issue that could damage the T5, but I could see it simply not working.

If the baseboard thermostat is *in series* with the contacts controlled by the T5, *both* the T5 *and* the baseboard thermostat need to call for heat to turn on the baseboard.

It's unlikely that the baseboard thermostat is *in parallel* with the contacts controlled by the T5 - that would be a bit of work to wire - but if that's the case, it would work as you want and it wouldn't damage the T5, or the relay / contactor.

> I just wish the T5 would go down low enough.

This is the real solution - swap out the T5 with a thermostat that works the way you want it to.